# How to apply background image for an templates in django

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

In my site, in a table of particular  I have to insert a image as background. I did that but the image looks like double image as the image is smaller than cell width and height it is getting overlap.

In background image cell I used no-repeat to end the repeat display of same image, but it is not working. I am designing web page using html in django framework.

template is

```
<td background="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/sample.JPG" no-repeat;>
```

May I know how to cancel the repeat display of same background image in a table cell.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like below... It will help you...

It `no repeats the image background` and it also `Stretch the image to Table Cell`..

**CSS:**

```
<style>
.tdStyle
{
background-image:url('{{ STATIC_URL }}images/sample.JPG');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:100%;
}
</style>
```

To Support Old Browsers you can add the below lines to CSS :

```
-moz-background-size: 100%; /* Gecko 1.9.2 (Firefox 3.6) */
-o-background-size: 100%; /* Opera 9.5 */
-webkit-background-size: 100%; /* Safari 3.0 */
-khtml-background-size: 100%; /* Konqueror 3.5.4 */
-moz-border-image: url(mtn.jpg) 0; /* Gecko 1.9.1 (Firefox 3.5) */
```

**HTML:**

```
<td class="tdStyle">
```

Comment: note: background-size is a CSS3 property it will not work for older browsers without including some javascript backup.

Answer (score 17):

Look how I did it:
In the template I put the following line:

```
<body id="bg" style="background-image: url('{% static "images/33.jpg"%}')";>
```

And in the css:

```
#bg{
    background-size: 1800px 900px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

As a result I obtained a fixed background and with the proportions of the screen.

Answer (score 6):

`'no-repeat'` is not a valid html attribute. Why aren't you using the style attribute OR a proper css included file?

```
<td style="background: url('{{ STATIC_URL }}images/sample.JPG') no-repeat;">
```

Comment: create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to give people a better understanding of the problem you are experiencing

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. if we use inline styles with background-image:url we have to make path manually.

```
<body id="bg" style="background-image: url('../images/33.jpg')";>
```

Answer (score 0):

in CSS you will do:

```
#.bg-image {
      
      background-size: 100%;
  
      background-position: center center;
  
      background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.bgded{
      background-image: url( "{% static 'images/ur.jpg' %}");
  }
```

Remember to load static page by adding

```
{% load static %}
```

at the top of your html page.